# Azure Container Service: Webhook recieves System.IO.IOException

Tags: azure, azure-app-services

I have followed this (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ci-cd) tutorial to setup Azure AppService with my own Docker Container (nginx container hosting an Angular app).

This works for some hours, but then it starts to fail. Every request results in the following error (excerpt from the HTML response in Azure Portal):

```
  <h1>System.IO.IOException</h1>
  <h2 class="exceptionMessage">Invalid handle to path &quot;/home/site&quot;</h2>
  <p><strong>Description:</strong> HTTP 500.Error processing request.</p><p><strong>Details:</strong> Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.</p>
<div><strong>Exception stack trace:</strong></div>
<div class="details">  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x0005e] in &lt;4dc8ec68b0964e099af86e50301f5f3c&gt;:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x0008f] in &lt;4dc8ec68b0964e099af86e50301f5f3c&gt;:0 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in &lt;4dc8ec68b0964e099af86e50301f5f3c&gt;:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with
```

My workaround is to disable "Continous Deployment" in the Docker menu from my AppService instance, delete the Webhook, and reenable "Continous Deployment", sometimes I also have to restart the instance. It then works again and pulls the newest version from the Container Repository, before it starts failing again. I'm using Webhook Ping from the Portal to determine if it works or not.

As I am new to Azure I have no idea where to start resolving this error.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Unfortunately, I couldn't fix it yet.